# I want put à in mail subject

Tags: php, html

I must create email and I have to put in the subject the word "legalità"

So I do:

```
$mail->Subject = $name."legalit&#224; ";
```

But when I read email I read `"namelegalit&#224;"`

I want put "à" character. Anyone can help me?

Comment: But it has the `à` character, as shown by your example "*But when I read email I read "namelegalità"*"

Comment: @james sorry stack overflow converts the characters in "à"

Comment: Why can't you just write  `$name."legalità "` without using html encoding?

Comment: ^ Especially since the mail subject **will** be text/plain.

Comment: can I have an example how to correct my code?

Comment: You've already got one with the comment from @JackSkeletron (you could literally copy/paste that into your code) - you can't use HTML encoding in the mail subject; it's part of the message header so it's plain text. Email was invented looooooong before HTML.

Comment: make sure everything is in the same character-encoding. and make sure that encoding is utf-8.